# Структура папок сайта. Как грамотней?

Tags: mvc, веб-программирование

В общем, планируется несложный сайт-визитка с небольшим количеством PHP, для вывода из базы данных товаров. Встал такой вопрос - как грамотно организовать структуру папок сайта, что к чему подключать и как разделять код? Можно коротко, думаю, я пойму общую идею. Пока что есть такой вариант:

```
/css
/js
/images
/includes
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
page3.php
```

PHP-файлы просто связаны между собой ссылками (в меню сайта), в нужные места этих файлов подключаются файлы из папки includes, которые выводят какие-то данные из базы. Как вариант - создать папку template для шаблонов, тогда туда буду передаваться данные из файлов папки includes и уже в главные файлы будут делаться не php-вставки, а вставляться шаблоны. То есть, получается, что index.php, page1.php, page2.php, page3.php это просто файлы с html-разметкой и php-вставками (или шаблонами). Есть еще какие-то, более грамотные варианты разделения?

Comment: И как организовывается подключение? Что должно быть в index.php? В двух словах, если не сложно.

Comment: С помощью htaccess или аналога скидываем все запросы на несуществующие файлы в index.php, который так или иначе знает, что page/{int} - это страница с id int, product/{int} - это продукт с id int и так далее. Если индекс видит незнакомый паттерн или не может найти запись, он выдает 404

Comment: А можно чуть-чуть поподробнее - как это выглядит? В одном из примеров я видел, что index.php организован так: оператором switch перебирается GET-параметр, например, $_GET['page'] и в зависимости от значения подключается та или иная страница. Это грамотный подход?

Comment: Для сайта-визитки - да, лучшим же вариантом будет сделать массив регулярок (например ^page/\d+$ => page) и по ним определять необходимое действие. Можно эти регулярки вынести в htaccess, а на стороне php использовать только switch по гет-переменным (RewriteRule page/(\d+) index.php?page_id=$1. По большому счету, все сводится к перебору вариантов, вопрос только в их сложности и автоматизированности. В любом случае сам этот функционал лучше поместить в отдельный класс/файл, а не держать в самом индексе.

Comment: Вот на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/ простейший MVC паттерн на примере сайта визитки.
Исходники здесь https://github.com/vitalyswipe/tinymvc/zipball/v0.1

Comment: Спасибо! Буду рад услышать другие ответы по теме, может быть ссылки на какие-то статьи, в интернете ничего подобного не нашел, в основном сложные темы про MVC, а мне бы что-нибудь попроще, для начинающего, так сказать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В идеале любой сайт должен иметь такую структуру:

```
app (корневая папка)
--core
--components
--models
--other code-related stuff
--templates
--public - именно эта папка смотрит "наружу"
----assets
----images
----js
----css
----index.php
--logs
```

Здесь главное - не названия папок, а то, что наружу смотрит всего одна папка и один исполняемый файл, в результате сайт у вас оказывается наименее уязвимым. И не забывайте применять intval() и подобные операции к приходящим айдишникам.

update: Еще одна вещь, которую необходимо отметить - если заливаются какие-то файлы, то надо их хранить **вне публичной директории**, либо (если, например, это пользовательские изображения, которые должны показываться) фильтровать их по расширению и быть уверенным, что сервер не может исполнять файлы с таким расширением. Буквально на этой неделе сталкивался с тем, что так сломали самопис (а в свое время так уронили тысячи сайтов на вордпрессе).

Comment: А, что в templates? Если там, к примеру статические шаблоны типа навигации, кнопок, футера, почему бы их не держать там же в /public?